# TikZ/Pgfplots - restrict expr to domain does not accept pgf macro

Tags: pgfplots, macros

First question here, so thank you all for welcoming it. When I try the option `restrict expr to domain` in `\addplot`, there seems to be no way for TikZ/PGF to understand a prior macro produced by `\pgfplotsextra`, while it works flawlessly with a macro produced by `\def`.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% libraries
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc, patterns}

% pgfplots settings
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={font=\small}}
\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={%
    clip=true,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xmin = 0, xmax=21,
    ymax = 10, ymin  = 0}
}

\begin{document}

% Custom functions
\makeatletter
\def\markxof#1{
    \pgf@process{#1}
    \pgfmathparse{\pgf@x/\pgfplotsunitxlength+\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x)/10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@x}
}
\def\intmarkxof#1{
    \pgf@process{#1}
    \pgfmathparse{int(int(\pgf@x/\pgfplotsunitxlength+\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x)/10))}
}
\def\intmarkxofnext#1{
    \pgf@process{#1}
    \pgfmathparse{int(int(\pgf@x/\pgfplotsunitxlength+\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x)/10))+1}
}
\makeatother

% Initial values
\def\myrzero{8.5}
\def\myrdelta{-0.2}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        mystyle,
        grid = none,
        grid style={dashed},
        xlabel={\emph{$t_i$}},
        xlabel style={at={(1.05,-0.15)}, anchor=south},
        legend cell align=left,
        legend pos=outer north east
    ]
        % Revenue curve
        \addplot[name path global=revenue,blue,domain=0:20] {\myrzero * exp(\myrdelta * \x)};

        % Costs
        \addplot+[name path global=cost, ybar interval,mark=no, red, fill=white] plot coordinates { 
            (0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0)  (3, 0.5) (4, 0.55) (5, 0.60) (6, 0.635) (7, 0.70) 
            (8, 0.725) (9, 0.75) (10, 0.8) (11, 0.85) (12, 0.95) (13, 1.15) (14, 1.25) 
            (15, 1.35) (16, 1.5) (17, 1.75) (18, 1.95) (19, 2) (20, 2.1)};

        % Intersection between revenue line and cost line
        \path [name intersections={of=revenue and cost, name=i}];
        \pgfplotsextra{
            \path (i-1) \pgfextra{\intmarkxof{i-1}\xdef\mylambda{\pgfmathresult}};
            \path (i-1) \pgfextra{\intmarkxofnext{i-1}\xdef\mylambdanext{\pgfmathresult}};
        }

        % Legend
        \legend{$r\left(t\right)$,$\left\{c_t\right\}$}

   \end{axis}
    % macros \mylambda and \mylambdanext are now defined

    \begin{axis}[
        mystyle,
        xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
        % Custom X ticks
        every extra x tick/.style={  
            tick0/.initial=1,
            tick1/.initial=7,
            xticklabel style={
                xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/tick\ticknum},
            },
        },
        extra x ticks={\mylambda,\mylambdanext},
        extra x tick labels={$t_\lambda$,$t_{\lambda+1}$},
        xticklabel style={anchor=north},
        % Custom Y ticks
        extra y ticks={\myrzero},
        extra y tick labels={$r_0$},
        extra y tick style={tickwidth=0mm},
        yticklabel style={xshift=17.5},
    ]

    % Highlight the cost bar at optimum point
    \addplot [name path global=cost2, ybar interval, mark=no, red, fill=red!50, restrict expr to domain={x}{\mylambda:\mylambdanext}] coordinates { 
        (0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 0)  (3, 0.5) (4, 0.55) (5, 0.60) (6, 0.635) (7, 0.70) 
        (8, 0.725) (9, 0.75) (10, 0.8) (11, 0.85) (12, 0.95) (13, 1.15) (14, 1.25) 
        (15, 1.35) (16, 1.5) (17, 1.75) (18, 1.95) (19, 2) (20, 2.1)};  

    % Draw optimum line to axis
    \draw[dashed] (i-1) -- ($(axis cs:0,-0.2)!(i-1)!(axis cs:20,-.2)$); 

    \end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

UPDATE (2): Thank you [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) for providing the right solution. It is indeed necessary to close the current axis and open a new one to be able to access `\mylambda` and `\mylambdanext`, as also pointed out by the pgfplots manual. I can now successfully create the figure below.

[image: GOAL]

Comment: Welcome! Can you minimise the example a bit? Or give some hints as to what's relevant? Where does `restrict expr to domain` occur?

Comment: Saying `\def\r` globally is an absolutely terrible idea. Don't do this. Saying `\def\delta` is a similarly awful idea. Don't do this either. `\def\costdelta` is not such a bad idea, but it is still a bad idea. Far better not to do this while you're at it.

Comment: You can't load libraries after `\begin{document}`. That needs to be in your preamble.

Comment: Note that `\def\r_0{n}` defines the macro `\r`. Moreover, not only `\r`, but also `\delta`, is already defined, but you're overwriting the definition. So `\delta` and `\r` will no longer work normally anywhere in your document.

Comment: Thank you @cfr! I tried to address all your remarks and updated my question accordingly. Hope you can give me some hints on why the macros `\mylambda` and `\mylambdanext` don't work as inputs to the `restrict expr to domain` option.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take another look. I eventually guessed that was the problem, but, by then, I couldn't stay awake and gave up ;).

Comment: The stuff in the `\pgfplotsextra` is not used until `\end{axis}`. In particular, it is being used ***after*** the code you have which uses `\mylambda` etc. I don't know what the definitions in the preamble are meant to do - I guess this is system layer stuff and I'm not familiar with that at all (and can't find it in the manual) - but this is why you get the undefined control sequence errors.

Comment: Thank you again @cfr. Your suggestion is correct, and I stumbled upon the same solution after reading the right passage in the pgfplots manual (p. 224): "any drawing commands inside of an axis need to be postponed until the axis is complete". I will updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Please don't post answers in questions. Either ask somebody to turn a comment into an answer or post an answer yourself, if you found the solution yourself. In this case, please post your solution as an answer. (I just pointed out the cause of the problem - I didn't give you an answer, so much better you answer.)

Comment: @cfr I thought I read somewhere that I would need 15 reputation to answer my own questions. If you would be willing to turn the solution into an answer I'd be happy to mark the question as solved.

Comment: I think you just can't answer your question immediately - it imposes some kind of wait. But your question is 2 days old, so I think it should be fine. Have you tried it? (I already voted for your question else I'd do it to push you over the 15.)

Comment: @cfr Could you write up an answer here?